# Which function will execute first in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to know which Function will execute first OnCommand or OnClientClick ?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnHRApprove" runat="server" Text="Approve" OnCommand="btnApprove_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidatePayrate()" CommandArgument="HR" CssClass="adLink" />
```

Comment: It will be `OnClientClick`

Comment: You can always test that by yourself putting break points(in your backend code)/ debugger(in javascript code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OnClientClick
```

executes first since it is executed on the client side, but is bound to only one controller, while

```
OnCommand
```

is also executed on client side but calls a server sided method and can be bound to several buttons with different Id:s, and then handled through a switch case to determine which the command is like:

```
  <asp:Button id="btnHRApprove"
       Text="approve"
       CommandName="ValidatePayrate"
       OnCommand="btnApprove_Click" 
       runat="server"/>

  <asp:Button id="btnSubmit"
       Text="Submit"
       CommandName="Submit"
       OnCommand="btnApprove_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

Then in the code behind(in this case C#), you can use a switch case to check which command is given rather than which button was clicked:

```
  void btnApprove_Click(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     switch(e.CommandName)
     {
        case "ValidatePayrate":
           //Your ValidatePayRate code here
           break;
        case "Submit":
           // Submit code here
           break;
        default:
           // Default
           break; 
     }
  }
```

If the client has javascript turned off, the OnClientClick will not fire and the OnCommand will fire instead

Answer (score 2):

```
 OnClientClick="return ValidatePayrate()"
```

This will execute first, based on its return value next function will execute,
if it returns false then further execution stops otherwise

```
OnCommand="btnApprove_Click"
```

will execute.

Answer (score 1):

When working in web applications it is always to remember that methods and calls are written for client side always execute first.

So in your case the method **ValidatePayrate()** will be fired first and if it returns false then server side function won't be executed.